# NSTimer Restarting

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

I have CountDown timer like below:

```
- (void)updateCounterLabel:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    if(secondsLeft > 0 ){

    secondsLeft -- ;
    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;

    countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];

}
else{
    secondsLeft = timeInterval;
}

-(void)countdownTimer   {
    if([timer isValid]){
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }       
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounterLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

----My problem is that every time recall this timer it increments like this : secondLeft-3 , secondLeft -5 ,secondLeft - 7..................

Each time my view loads, i create a new timer, but the old ones still exist.in my timer's action method, i am decrementing an index variable that keeps track of the seconds, and each timer runs that method every time it fires. So, if i have three timers, the index will decrements by three each time.

For example:

First Load: 60, 59, 58...

Second Load: 60, 58, 56...

Third Load: 60, 57, 54...

Question : How can i restart or recreate a timer without above problem?  somebody help me out pls.

Comment: where you restart or recreate a timer - any button click? and what is the starting value of secondsLeft?

Comment: I dont think secondLeft value is relevant here.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem ? what do you mean by decrement is enlarging ? are you sure countdownTimer is called only one time ?

Comment: I am sure i called the timer a lot of times , thats why i am asking for help to restart the timer ?

Comment: I tested your code and its decrements by 1 correctly even after running/stopping countdownTimer several times. Your code is convoluted. I would start by using properties for all your variables and then report back.

Comment: You should, of course, only start one timer and let it repeat.  But that appears to be what you're doing, assuming that "countdownTimer" is what starts you timer.  But keep in mind that the display is only refreshed on "refresh cycles".  You can try doing a `setNeedsDisplay` on the label, to see if that makes it refresh sooner.

Comment: thank you  . The timer is called from viewDidload and only  when reload the view the problem occur

Comment: (You clearly omitted some code when you pasted it in, since "updateCounterLabel" has no closing `}`.  Did you omit anything important?)

Comment: "only when reload the view the problem occur" - Sounds like you're getting more than one copy of the timer going.

Comment: Each time my view loads, i create a new timer, but the old ones still exist.in my timer's action method, i am  decrementing an index variable that keeps track of the seconds, and each timer runs that method every time it fires. So, if i have three timers, the index will decrease by three each time.

Comment: @Ezimettekin: Where is `secondsLeft` declared? What does "reload the view" exactly mean?

Comment: I am calling the viewDidLoad from another place, secondsLeft is time interval(gloabel variable ) that changes according to current time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...];
```

call *retains the target* (the view controller) while the timer is running,
so that the view controller 
is *never deallocated* and the timer continues to run even if the view controller
is popped off the navigation stack or dismissed.

Therefore, if the view is loaded again, you have two instances of the view controller and
therefore two timers, which both decrement the same global variable `secondsLeft`.

This hopefully explains why the value is decremented by two each second.

As a solution, you can create the timer in `viewWillAppear`, and **invalidate** it 
in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: @Ezimettekin: Did you remove the timer creation from `viewDidLoad`? Otherwise you would have two timers: one from `viewDidLoad` and one from `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @Ezimettekin: Perhaps add NSLog to viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear to check how many instances of the view controller are running.

Comment: @Ezimettekin: I do not have much experience with container view controllers. As this is a separate problem, you might better post a new question where you can show the related code.